# Lucee ORM - Duplicate entry on primary key

Tags: orm, lucee

I have been working with Lucee (coldfusion) for some time now and I can't resolve a certain issue we're having. We use the ORM framework with entities to work with data. It's all working nicely except one thing:

We have an external API that **doesn't** use the ORM framework. I use mysql queries to insert a row in a table. Works all fine and dandy, but if I go to our ORM application and try to save a second row then I get a "Duplicate Entry for key PRIMARY" error.

So it's clear to me the ORM framework isn't up to date with the externally added row. How do I tell ORM to reload this data? ORMReload() is very slow so I don't want to use that (and that's for the whole structure). EntityReload isn't working either.

A simple example on how I use the ORM framework:

```
var simple_item = entityNew("item");
entitySave(simple_item);
ormFlush();
```

So anyone got an idea how I can fix this? Thanks in advance!

P.S. Currently I set the primary key with a function inside the entity instead of using generator="increment" to make it work, but that's just a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently I set the primary key with a function inside the entity instead of using generator="increment"

Are you sure "increment" is the appropriate generator algorithm? From the [Adobe docs](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/coldfusion-orm/define-orm-mapping/map-the-properties.html), which also apply to Lucee ORM (my emphasis):

> increment: This algorithm generates identifiers of type long, short,
> or int by incrementing a counter maintained by ORM. This is commonly
> used when auto-generation for the primary key is not enabled in the
> table and you want ORM to generate the primary key. **This should be
> used when a single instance of ColdFusion is the only process to
> insert data into the table**.

If a non-ORM process can also insert data then you should be letting the database handle primary key increments natively and instead use

```
generator="native"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! Well it is a incremental column, the workaround just get's the latest ID at that time and increases it with 1. So in short: ORM works well with incremental. The external source works well with incremental. But if you add one in the external source and after that you add one in the ORM source then you get a primary key error because somehow ORM doesn't see the newly added row.

Comment: If the column is defined as "auto-increment" then you should use `generator="native"` as suggested. Using `increment` means you are letting ORM handle the ID generation, hence the error because ORM and your DB are in conflict.

Comment: ah thanks man that sounds logical, I will try it ^^